# Floating point formatting in printf()

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have an array of floats where data are stored with varying decimal points so some are `123.40000`, `123.45000`, `123.45600`...now if i want to print these values in the string without the 0s in the end in `printf()` so that they are `123.4`, `123.45`, `123.456`, without those 0s in the end. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the %g formatter:

```
printf( "%g", 123.4000 );
```

prints

123.4

Trailing zeros are removed, but unfortunately so is the trailing decimal point if the fractional part is zero. I don't know if there is actually any way of doing what you want directly using printf() - I think something like this is probably your best bet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void print( FILE * f, double d ) {
    if ( d - floor(d) == 0.0 ) {
        fprintf( f, "%g.", d );
    }
    else {
        fprintf( f, "%g", d );
    }
}

int main() {
    print( stdout, 12.0 );
    print( stdout, 12.300 );
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to compare doubles? "if (d-floor(d) == 0.0)"?

Comment: @himself No, it's fine when you know what you are doing. “Never compare floating-point numbers for `==`” is just an approximation for the unsophisticated.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how hacky this is but:

http://codepad.org/e3Q3pUNd

```
float f = 124.000;
if (f == (int) f) {
    printf("%.1f\n", f); /* .1 can be changed */
} else {
    printf("%g\n", f);
}
```

Returns `124.0`.

```
float f = 124.123000;
if (f == (int) f) {
    printf("%.1f\n", f); /* .1 can be changed */
} else {
    printf("%g\n", f);
}
```

Returns `124.123`.

Answer (score 0):

Use %g --

Print a double in either normal or exponential notation, whichever is more appropriate for its magnitude. 'g' uses lower-case letters, 'G' uses upper-case letters. This type differs slightly from fixed-point notation in that insignificant zeroes to the right of the decimal point are not included. Also, the decimal point is not included on whole numbers.

Comment: just a small query, what if i want to remove the trailing zeros but want to keep the decimal in whole numbers, like 124.00000 is 123.

Answer (score 0):

Print to a (large enough) buffer. Print the buffer ... and if the there's no `'.'` in the buffer print a dot.

```
char buf[100];
sprintf(buf, "%g", val);
printf("%s", buf);
if (strchr(buf, '.') == NULL) putchar('.');
```

---

*edit*

The Standard specifies the `#` flag:

> # The result is converted to an ``alternative  form''. [...] For a, A,
>   e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions, the result of converting a floating-point
>   number always contains a decimal-point character, even if no digits follow
>   it. [...] For g and G conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from
>   the  result. [...]

... but you get the trailing zeros :(